# My WordPress got hacked through an infected .htaccess file and here's its content, what does this htaccess do?

Tags: regex, wordpress, .htaccess, malware

After scanning a client's server for malware, I found that an .htaccess file was infected with the following malware:

```
SL-HTACCESS-GENERIC-ln.UNOFFICIAL
```

Here's the content of the .htaccess file:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 5 minutes"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresDefault "access plus 6 hours"
</IfModule>
<ifModule mod_headers.c>
Header set X-Endurance-Cache-Level "2"
</ifModule>
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(denaturization)([0-9]+)-(.*)--a([0-9]+)\/(.*)$ ?denaturization$2=$4&%{QUERY_STRING}[L]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
# php -- BEGIN cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
# Set the “ea-php73” package as the default “PHP” programming language.
<IfModule mime_module>
AddHandler application/x-httpd-ea-php73 .php .php7 .phtml
</IfModule>
# php -- END cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
```

can someone please tell me what does this file do and whether it's safe to delete this file and replace it with the original htaccess that is shipped with WordPress

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteRule ^(denaturization)([0-9]+)-(.*)--a([0-9]+)\/(.*)$ ?denaturization$2=$4&%{QUERY_STRING}[L]
> ```

This is the only line that is out-of-place in the above `.htaccess` file. And the only line that you would need to remove in order to return the `.htaccess` file to relative normality. However, if a site has been "infected" then this is unlikely to be the only change? By itself, this doesn't really do anything - except maybe highlight to a hacker that the site is vulnerable. It's more likely that this is *talking* to a back-end script that does the do.

However, this directive isn't strictly well-formed, as there is no *space* before the `RewriteRule` flags argument (ie. `...%{QUERY_STRING}<here>[L]`). Although this may not affect the intended functionality of the *malware*.

This would internally rewrite a URL of the form:

```
/denaturization123-foo--a456/bar?baz=abc
```

to:

```
/?denaturization123=456&baz=abc[L]
```

Which would allow the request to be routed through WordPress - displaying the homepage.

However, this doesn't make much sense taken out of context.

I would check the server access logs to see if there have been any requests for URLs that start `/denaturization` and take note of the specific URLs.